# How to run a Maya Python script under a condition

Tags: python, maya

I want to create a condition that right after a specific node is created the second script can run. However, it is not giving me an error but is also not working. Any thoughts?

Note: the node that I am trying to check is only display on the DAG Objects. I don't know if this will affect the search of the object.

import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

def active_node():

##check for constraint node to activate the next script

```
source = 'constraintNode'
```

def is_node_active():
return cmds.isTrue(source)

```
cmds.condition('source_active', initialize=True, dependency=source, script=is_node_active)
    
if cmds.isTrue('source_active'):
    print 'run next script'
else:
    print 'Try again'
```

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? See [ask].

Comment: Your code formating is wrong and the mel script `is_node_active` is missing. But if you have to check the condition anyway, why do you use a condition at all? You could simply check the result of the mel scritpt directly.